# SP2013 - Sporadic error when editing PPT using Office 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, office

We have a few users that are having sporadic issues when trying to open up Office documents. All users still using Office 2007 are fine, it is only users that use Office 2013 that have the issue.They click on the document, the splash screen for Word/Excel/PowerPoint shows up, the document opens in Read Only mode and when they click on Edit Document

> We're having trouble connecting to the server. If this keeps happening, contact your help desk.

This is somewhat sporadic. A document I could open yesterday does not open today. Originally Check Out/In was not turned on for this library, then they turned it on, now they've turned it off. It happens to both in-house and remote employees (on VPN), on both wired and wireless connections.

Any ideas?

The document library was created from SP not VS so there is no "/List/" in the URL. (Url looks like this

> http://share.name/docs/ClassF/F300/filename

There is only 1 version of Office on the computer - Office 2013 - and I have had any and all Office and Win 7 updates applied.

Authentication for this site is Windows (NTLM) so nothing unusual there. They are not using Office Web Apps.

The strange thing is that in the document library, some documents work and others do not.

There's nothing in the event viewer. Ran Fiddler and I see a couple of 401 results (I'm not a Fiddle expert by any means) and found this in the ULS logs:

Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'http://share.name/docs/ClassF/F300/fileName.pptx' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.

How does the Office 2013 client authenticate to SP? What am I missing?

Comment: [This article](http://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/office-2013-error-sorry-we-are-having-some-temporary-server-issues/) can be usefull

Comment: Is Office 2013 the only version installed (i.e. do they have some 2007/2010/2013 mixed clients)?  Are they any entries on the client application log (specifically around the web client service)?  Tools that can help get more info:  Fiddler and Office 2013 Telemetry tool (Installs with Office 2013).